# Can fastlane skip `before_all` or `after_all` in certain lanes?

Tags: ios, fastlane

I was wondering if there is a way for certain lanes to skip the `before_all` or `after_all` blocks for certain/specified lanes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
before_all do |lane|
  if lane == :test
    puts "Do something for test"
  else
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

addition relating to your comment

```
lanes = [:test, :foo, :bar]
lanes.include?(:test) # => true
lanes.include?(:baz) # => false
```

so you can do something like

```
before_all do |lane|
  lanes_to_say_foo = [:test, :build, :other]
  if lanes_to_say_foo.include?(lane)
    puts "Foo"
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! But what we want a condition for multiple lanes? Is there like an `if lane in some array of lanes`?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `if [:test, :beta].include?(lane)`. It's all standard Ruby you can use :)

Comment: I added this to my answer :-)